Create Multiple Pages PDF using HTML/CSS div (Angular 16)
I have been trying to create a PDF of an HTML div "templateContainer". templateContainer consists of an HTML that contains the design of a Resume/CV.
See the following code block:
 <ng-template ngbNavContent>
     <div class="spinner" *ngIf="changingTemplate">
         <div class="loader"></div>
     </div>
    <div *ngIf="!changingTemplate">
         <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
              <!-- Wrapper for buttons -->
              <div class="col-12 col-md-8 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-md-end align-items-center mb-2">
                   <!-- Preview Template Button -->
                   <button (click)="showTemplate()" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-md mt-1 mb-1 me-md-2">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-image me-1"></i> Preview Template
                   </button>           
                   <!-- Download Template Button -->
                   <a *ngIf="resumeData.resumeTemplate.id" (click)="downloadTemplateAsPDF()" target="_blank" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-md mt-1 mb-1">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-file-document-outline me-1"></i> Download Template PDF
                   </a>
              </div>
         </div>
                              
         <div class="row text-center mt-3 ms-1 me-1 mb-3">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let template of designTemplates">
                   <div class="col-md-2" role="button" (click)="chooseTemplate(template);applyTemplate(selectedTemplateId)">
                       <img src="attachments/resume/{{template.image}}" alt="Card image cap" class="img-fluid"
                                                 [ngClass]="selectedTemplateId === template.id ? 'b-active' : ''">
                           <div class="p-3"><h4 class="card-title">{{template.name}}</h4></div>
                   </div>
              </ng-container>
         </div>

         <div id="t-wrap" class="d-none">
             <div *ngIf="resumeData.resumeTemplate.id && templateHtml && !isLoading && !changingTemplate" id="templateContainer" [innerHTML]="templateHtml"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </ng-template>

I have used "d-none" only to hide the HTML template on the UI but it will be temporarily removed when I click the 'Download PDF' button.
On clicking the download pdf button I'm calling the below function:
downloadTemplateAsPDF() {
    this.changingTemplate = true;
    let wrap = document.getElementById('t-wrap');
    if (wrap) {
      wrap.classList.remove('d-none');
    }

    const element = document.getElementById('templateContainer');
    if (element) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      element.classList.add('pdf-styling');

      // Create a new jsPDF instance
      const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

      // Fetch all divs with classes n-0, n-1, n-2, etc.
      const pageElements = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="n-"]');

      // Function to capture each div and add to PDF
      const captureAndAddToPDF = async (index: number) => {
        if (index >= pageElements.length) {
          // If all elements are processed, save the PDF
          pdf.save(`${this.resumeData.firstName}-${this.resumeData.lastName}.pdf`);
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.changingTemplate = false;
          element.classList.remove('pdf-styling');
          if (wrap) {
            wrap.classList.add('d-none');
          }
          return;
        }

        const pageElement = pageElements[index] as HTMLElement;

        try {
          // Ensure visibility and modify problematic styles
          pageElement.style.display = 'block';
          pageElement.style.position = 'relative';

          // Capture the current page element
          const canvas = await html2canvas(pageElement, {
            scrollY: 0,
            useCORS: true,
            backgroundColor: null, // Ensures transparent background if needed
            logging: true,         // Enable logging to track capture process
            removeContainer: true, // Removes the cloned canvas to avoid interference
          });

          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
          const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
          const imgWidth = canvas.width;
          const imgHeight = canvas.height;
          const ratio = pageWidth / imgWidth;
          const scaledWidth = imgWidth * ratio;
          const scaledHeight = imgHeight * ratio;

          // Add the image to the PDF
          pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pageWidth, scaledHeight);

          // Add a new page if there are more elements to process
          if (index < pageElements.length - 1) {
            pdf.addPage();
          }

          // Process the next element
          await captureAndAddToPDF(index + 1);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error capturing element at index ${index}:`, error);
        }
      };

      // Start capturing from the first element
      captureAndAddToPDF(0);

    }
  }

Problem: I'm able to get n-0 div from the code but when it moves to the next index n-1 or n-2, it does not find it. It returns null in that case.
Required Solution: I want to print the pages of Resume/CV in PDF but page by page. templateContainer will have the pages in it labelled as n-0, n-1, n-2 and so on. n-0 will be the first page of pdf, n-1 will be the second and so on. The first page is printed but on 2nd page it says Error capturing element at index 1: Unable to find element in cloned iframe
Looking forward to the possible solutions.
